# Can I rollback Umbraco to recover a lost stylesheet

Tags: umbraco

I had umbraco crash while editing a stylesheet and it has completely wiped out the contents of it. Is there a way to recover this?

The demo app is hosted in Azure.

Comment: Only way you can do it is if the solution is under source control, or if you have a database backup (the table to look for is `cmsStylesheet`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only if you've got a backup of the file in source control. Umbraco only lets you roll back page content.

Comment: Thanks. Was able to recover the css from a testers machine. Dodged a bullet. Thanks, Tim

Answer (score 0):

If you're lucky, and I have been several times, what crashes the website does not take down the Umbraco backoffice.  So, if you are still on the page that emptied. Try holding Ctrl and Z to undo what was done.